# Фильтр вызова MOCK_METHOD-а по значению аргумента с типом строки C-style

Tags: c++, c, юнит-тесты, gtest, gmock

Использую библиотеку Google Mock в тестировании.
Описываю mock метод класса:

```
MOCK_METHOD1(methodName, void(const char *param));
```

Задаю правило:

```
char expectedParam[] = "exp_value";
EXPECT_CALL(mockObject, methodName(expectedParam));
```

В результате получаю fail из-за сравнения C-style строк. Есть ли способ это обойти без изменения типа `param` на `std::string`?

Comment: @VTT, да, конечно.. но надеюсь, что в библиотеки это могли как то решить.

Comment: фейл скорее всего из-за сравнения указателей, а не c-style строк. По идее для сравнения строк там был StrMatch элемент

Comment: @VTT, в вопросе речь не о простом сравнении actual/expected, смысл в указании значения аргумента для функции (типа фильтр), которую нужно замокать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте матчер `StrEq`.

```
using ::testing::StrEq;
EXPECT_CALL(mockObject, methodName(StrEq(expectedParam)));
```